# How to do a macro that returns a match based on another macro

Tags: rust, macros

I have this macro:

```rust
macro_rules! str_to_num {
    ("one") => { 1 };
    ("two") => { 2 };
    ("three") => { 3 };
}
```

But I want to be able to use it with values decided on runtime:

```rust
fn main() {
    let value = str_to_num!(&args[1]);
}
```

So I would like to do another macro that generates a `match` using the `str_to_num` macro. How can I do it? Maybe using recursive macros?

Comment: Can you add an example on what you'd want to be generated for `str_to_num!(&args[1])`, what's `args` in this context? I can't see how you intend the "other macro" to interact, an example here would be great, too. But bear in mind that macros are evaluated at *compile time* so they can't rely on *runtime* values, they can only generate code that does.

Comment: Why not rewrite `str_to_num!()` to generate a `match` itself? At this point, just make it a function.

Comment: The point of using macros is that you're generating code at compile-time, i.e. the final code will only contain `2` where `str_to_num!("two")` is in the source. `&args[1]` is a dynamic value that is not yet known at compile time, so you can't use macros to match over it.

Comment: @FZs but I want to generate a `match` using the macro.